# MaterialUI show an other view after onclick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm completely new in MaterialUI. I'm working on my first project right now and trying to make use of templates form its page. I've loaded two .tsx files with log in view and main dashboard view. I'd like to show main dashboard view after clicking Login button on log in view. Both files have its own **export default function FnName()** function with   **const classes = useStyles();** and it seems to cause my problems. The way of using hooks is the issue here I guess. But how to pass this function to onClick handler event button? You can see my project here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-leftpad-6nwv2?file=/src/SignIn.tsx

Somebody can help?

Comment: Hello Matt your codesandbox is missing your app.js file and appears to be missing a lot of code. Could you please add more information to your codesandbox so we can better help you? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, should be OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this example:

**App Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import SignIn from "./material-ui/signin-template/SignIn";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory as history} from 'history';
import MiniDrawer from "./material-ui/signin-template/Dashboard";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={SignIn}/>
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={MiniDrawer}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

**SingIn Component**

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import {Redirect, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

function Copyright() {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
            {"Copyright © "}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
                Your Website
            </Link>{" "}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {"."}
        </Typography>
    );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
    },
    form: {
        width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
    }
}));

export default function SignIn() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let history = useHistory();

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline/>
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                    <LockOutlinedIcon/>
                </Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Sign in
                </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        id="email"
                        label="Email Address"
                        name="email"
                        autoComplete="email"
                        autoFocus
                    />
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        name="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary"/>}
                        label="Remember me"
                    />
                    <Button
                        onClick={()=>{
                            history.push('/dashboard')
                        }}
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.submit}
                    >
                        Sign In
                    </Button>
                    <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                Forgot password?
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </div>
            <Box mt={8}>
                <Copyright/>
            </Box>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

**Dashboard Component**

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import {
  createStyles,
  makeStyles,
  useTheme,
  Theme
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import MapOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MapOutlined";
import DriveEtaOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DriveEtaOutlined";
import PeopleAltOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PeopleAltOutlined";
import DirectionsOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DirectionsOutlined";
import AssessmentOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AssessmentOutlined";
import ReportProblemOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ReportProblemOutlined";
import AccountCircleOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircleOutlined";
import { Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import ExitToAppIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: "flex"
    },
    appBar: {
      zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
      })
    },
    appBarShift: {
      marginLeft: drawerWidth,
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      })
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: 36
    },
    hide: {
      display: "none"
    },
    drawer: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
      whiteSpace: "nowrap"
    },
    drawerOpen: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      })
    },
    drawerClose: {
      transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
      }),
      overflowX: "hidden",
      width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        width: theme.spacing(9) + 1
      }
    },
    toolbar: {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "flex-end",
      padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
      // necessary for content to be below app bar
      ...theme.mixins.toolbar
    },
    content: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      padding: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  })
);

function MiniDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let history = useHistory();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
              [classes.hide]: open
            })}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open
        })}
        classes={{
          paper: clsx({
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open
          })
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <IconButton
          onClick={() => {
            history.push("/");
          }}
        >
          <ExitToAppIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Mapa", "Pojazdy", "Kierowcy", "Trasy", "Raporty", "Alerty"].map(
            (text, index) => (
              <ListItem
                button
                key={text}
                onClick={event => {
                  console.log(event.currentTarget);
                  history.push("/");
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index === 0 && <MapOutlinedIcon />}
                  {index === 1 && <DriveEtaOutlinedIcon />}
                  {index === 2 && <PeopleAltOutlinedIcon />}
                  {index === 3 && <DirectionsOutlinedIcon />}
                  {index === 4 && <AssessmentOutlinedIcon />}
                  {index === 5 && <ReportProblemOutlinedIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            )
          )}
        </List>
      </Drawer>

      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Typography paragraph />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MiniDrawer;
```

**Here is the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-pond-2qdw4)**

Comment: Every time I buid it, it fails. Can you run a project in https://codesandbox.io/index2 and show me the working solution with link? I'd be grateful.

Comment: Hi, I have added Code Sandbox in my answer. Please check it

Comment: Does it work from your side? When I click Sign In button I'm getting an error:

Cannot read property 'push' of undefined (onClick /src/SignIn.js:93:22).

Comment: hi, please check this (it is working) https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-pond-2qdw4

Comment: it works! Thank you! I'm moving forward with MaterialUI and React now.